# How to retrieve data from database using jQuery and information in a form from a previous page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to get a user's first name so that I can display it on my chatting app. I have the user's information. I can get the user by playing around with res.render(). In jade I can do something like #{user.firstName} to have it printed out but I am not sure how I can use this data in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you can build an element as follwed:

case 1

```
 <input id='user-first_name' type='hidden' value='#{user.firstName}' />

 // Then you can use the value of input field as.
 var firstName = $('#user-first_name').val()
```

case 2

you can directly write a script tag where you will initialize some window variables as :

```
<script>
window.user_first_name = #{user.firstName}
</script>
```

case 3

Also you can try assigning that value to data field of any html element(html tag) as followed :

```
<element data-first_name='#{user.firstName}'>

// Now you can use a jquery selector for selecting that element and you 
// will be able to retrieve that value using data function
var firstName = $(element_selector).data('first_name');
```